# Text to speech from string resource

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I cannot seem to get a TextToSpeech example to get the text from a string resource. I can get it to work fine from a textView/textEdit on the push of a button, but what I am after is users to push a button and texttospeech says what ever is associated with the @String resource for that button. Is this possible?

i.e. - If I wanted to add a custom marker to a map I would use:

```
.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

I cannot find any information for getting @string for text to speech

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For text to speech from a string resource, try this:

String me = "Hi";

```
    Tts.speak(me,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
            null);
```

Hope that helps